# Can a function from an interval to a set of rational numbers be bijective?

Tags: functions, logic

I have the next function:
$$g:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$$

Can it be bijective? Or is it at most surjective or one-to-one?

---

I believe that because there are more elements in the domain than in the range, then it cannot be one-to-one, but it can be surjective. Is that true? I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: You're basically right, but you have to be careful about the exact meaning of "more elements in the domain than in the range."  It isn't sufficient for the range to be a proper subset of the domain, since both sets are infinite; the range must have strictly lower cardinality.

Comment: @BrianTung got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be one-to-one by  the cardinality argument you gave. It can be surjective: Take $g(x)=x$ if $ x\in (0,1)\cap \mathbb Q$ and $g(x)=\frac1 2 $ for all other $x$.

Comment: By the way, if the function was: $$g:[0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$$, what would it be? is it surjective or one by one? because it is almost the same I guess.

Comment: @Brian Tung I will be glad to hear from you too.

Comment: No, in this case $g$ can be  bijective! The domain and the range of $g$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: Thank you so much!